# Android : Initialize ParseObject with a HashMap of values

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am loading some data from a `ParseCloud` function and I want to create a PFObject from this data.

With iOS, I'm doing this and it works fine:

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "myParseCloudFunction", withParameters: parameters) { 
    (success, error) in
        if let objects = success as? [[String : Any]] {
            let myObjectsArray: [MyCustomObject] = objects.map({
                (object) -> MyCustomObject in
                    let myCustomObject = MyCustomObject(dataSource: PFObject(className: "MyCustomObject", dictionary: object))
            })
        }
})
```

From the docs, I could read that I'm actually using this initializer:

```
+ (instancetype)objectWithClassName:(NSString *)className dictionary:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)dictionary;
```

> Creates a new `PFObject` with a class name, initialized with data 
>   constructed from the specified set of objects and keys.
>
> @param className The object's class.  @param dictionary An
>   `NSDictionary` of keys and objects to set on the new `PFObject`.
>
> @return A PFObject with the given class name and set with the given
>   data.

However, I can't find anything similar with Android. What to do then ?